# Generalised what?? CIrcle or line or ???..

Tags: geometry, terminology, symmetry

What is the term for all objects that share the following property

For any two different points in the shape the perpendicular bisector is an axis of symmetry of the shape.

So for 2 dimensional euclidean geometry it could be about a circle or a line

In 2 dimensional hyperbolic geometry it could be about a circle, line, horocycle or hypercycle

In 3 dimensionional euclidean geometry could be about a line circle, plane or a sphere. (The perpendicular bisector being a plane)

In 3 dimensions hyperbolic geometry could be about a line, circle, horocycle, hypercycle, plane, sphere, horosphere or hypersphere.

In other 3 dimensional geometries also other shapes could fall under this property.(am interested in which they are)

Bonus question:
This property also seems to include other properties (the shape has a constant curvature being one of them, are there others?

Comment: Do you have a source or proofs for the characterization of these shapes in each space? I'm curious whether there aren't exotic sets that fulfil the criterion. Some everywhere dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ seems like it could work (depending on whether you'd count that as a "shape"). The whole plane of course would.

Comment: Following on from my previous comment, the set of just vertices of a triangle or square, with no edges, would also work.

Comment: That opens a whole orher can of worms,but that is mainly sets/area  wihb only a very limited amount of points (allready with the vertices oc a pentagon it stops to be the case

Comment: It might depend upon the space in which it is embedded. For example a pair of points on a plane is a pair of points but on a line it's a circle.

Comment: The word "object/shape" has no precise mathematical meaning (in the context of geometry). Do you mean a subset of some metric space? Do you assume that the subset is closed? Connected? Anything else?

Comment: Where you write "For any two different points the perpendicular bisector is an axis of symmetry." do you mean "For any two different points the perpendicular bisector ***of the shape*** is an axis of symmetry." or "For any two different points the perpendicular bisector ***of the two points*** is an axis of symmetry."?  Next, do you mean "...is an axis of symmetry of the two points" or "...is an axis of symmetry of the shape"?

Comment: @Moishe-Kohan ,shapes like an ordinary circle and line, guess connected not sure about closed or open.

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby For any two different points, the perpendicular bisector **of those two points** is an axis of symmetry **of the shape**. It's not clear what a "perpendicular bisector" of the shape would even mean, nor would it make sense for two points to have a specific "axis of symmetry"

Comment: Try to define "objects" and "shapes" by editing the question, to the best of your ability. Otherwise, your question is impossible to answer. In 2d, if you assume that your objects are smooth curves, then these are exactly maximal curves of constant curvature.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I was thinking of a scenario in which the centrepoint of two points on a line could be considered an axis of symmetry of a 1-sphere. Maybe all points are perpendicular to two points on a line. Seems logical to me.